# Accessing File Stored on a server in my servlet

Tags: java, servlets

In my servlet file im trying to access a file stored on the server,and then im converting it to inputstream and storing it into the database.
if I try with local file,Its doing well,but when I try to access the file stored in my server it is showing 500 exception. that the directory cannot be identified.

Note : when I copy this directory and paste it in url,its working fine and showing the image.

Here is my code,

```
InputStream inputStream = null;        
  inputStream =  new FileInputStream("http://www.example.com/images/community.gif");
```

and this is for local,

```
 inputStream =  new FileInputStream("D:/INDIGOWORK/PostFreeAd/WebContent/images/community.gif");
```

Its working fine.Please solve my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `URL`:

```
InputStream in = new URL("http://www.example.com/images/community.gif")
    .openStream();
```

Comment: It is showing java.net.UnknownHostException: yourSite

Comment: Because most likely you're behind a proxy or firewall which does not let you pass. Same thing with me, but if I replace the `URL` to an address being on my local network, it works. You need to configure your Java to use proper proxy.

Answer (score 0):

try

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#openStream()

```
InputStream input = new URL("http://yourSite/images/community.gif").openStream();
```